# Is there a faster way to search a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpy array of roughly 3125000 entries the data is structured using the following dtype

```
dt = np.dtype([('startPoint', '<u8' ), ('endPoint', '<u8')])
```

The data is from a file that has been previously sorted by endPoint before it is read into the array.

I now need to search the array and check if it contains a particular endpoint and I'm doing this using a binary search using the following code

```
def binarySearch(array, index):
lowPoint = 0
highpoint = len(array) - 1


while (lowPoint <= highpoint):
    midPoint = int((lowPoint + highpoint) / 2)

    if(index == array[midPoint]['endPoint']):
        return midPoint

    elif(index < array[midPoint]['endPoint']):
        highpoint = midPoint - 1

    else:
        lowPoint = midPoint + 1

return -1
```

My question is is there a faster way to search for an entry in this array. As in is there a built in Numpy search that may be faster than my binary search.

Comment: [numpy.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) binary search implemented in C

Comment: I've looked over the scipy page for searchSorted but I'm not clear on how I can use it to compare to the custom dtype that I created. Is there a link to examples that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), also you can use [memory mapping](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) if the array is too large. searchsorted is implemented as binary search.

Comment: If the numpy array contains dtypes how do you structure the searchsorted for this? In my instance index is a long, but whats being searched for is in the array[x][endPoint]

Comment: @Scott that's exactly what you would pass to `np.searchsorted`, i.e. `arr['endPoint'].searchsorted(x)`

Comment: So when the searchsorted is finished, I should look in the array at the returned index to see if it is the element I'm searching for?
`def contains(array, x): return x == array[array.searchsorted(x)]` Is this a good example of usage?